# Can't start live chat and slow response on Appcelerator Support

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

Not sure if it's only me, but as of one month ago, I can't see the live chat button on the Appcelerator website. I've tried multiple browsers and VPNs but I can't seem to get in touch with the Appcelerator Support Team.

1) Does any one know if they removed this support service from the Indie plan?

2) Does anyone know a good way of getting service, as I don't hear anything for ages when contacting via email at support@appcelerator.com

I have an Indie account but see the below text at https://developer.appcelerator.com/help

"Ask our Support
The current plan for MY ORG does not include Appcelerator Support. Please consider our other Plans or Ask the Community."

Comment: I've create a JIRA entry at https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-4856

Comment: depending on your question you could ask it on stackoverflow or in the TiSlack channel (https://ti-slack.slack.com)

Comment: @miga who should I contact to enable my registration on TiSlack?

Comment: NVM, I found the link at http://tislack.org/signup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got a response from Appcelerator, see below:

> Hello, We have revoked our support of live chat from the platform web page for the indie users. It is now only enabled for users with pro, enterprise, cloud and trial plans. Thanks.